# How do I modify my SQL Query to take into account this specific filtering condition?

Tags: sql-server, filter, where-clause

I am using SQL Query 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query running against my database:

```
use My Database

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT a.ReservationStayID,
       c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
       a.StayDate,
       DATEPART(MONTH,a.StayDate) AS 'Month',
       DATEPART(YEAR,a.StayDate) AS 'Year',
       c.[MTH], 
       a.PackagePlanCode,
       c.[Market Segment Code],
       c.[CurrencyCode],
       a.RateAmount,
       SUM(a.RateAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY a.ReservationStayID) AS 'CUM_Rate',
       d.[Exchange Rate],
       ((a.RateAmount * d.[Exchange Rate])/1.15) AS 'PR',
       c.[PropertyCode],
       C.[Room Nights],
       c.[Tour Operator],
       c.[Group Booking ID],
       c.[Source of Business],
       c.[Booking Origin (1)], 
       c.[Market FINAL],
       c.[CreatedOn],
       c.[CreatedOn_RSD]

FROM ReservationStayDate a

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT *

FROM [RESERVATIONLIST]) c ON c.[ReservationStayID] = a.ReservationStayID and c.[MTH] = datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar)

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT *

FROM [PKGREVENUE]) d ON d.[ReservationStayID] = a.ReservationStayID AND d.[StayDate] = a.StayDate

WHERE c.[Status] <> 'CANCELED'
) q

WHERE q.CUM_Rate <> 0 

ORDER BY q.ReservationStayID, q.StayDate
```

The above query runs fine but now I want to include a filter where the following `ReservationStayID` are INCLUDED in the output: `152, 167, 658, 900`

These `ReservationStayID` all have their `CUM_Rate = 0`, meaning that they are automatically excluded in the output of my existing query.

I've tried the following but it did not work:

```
WHERE (q.CUM_Rate <> 0 AND q.ReservationStayId IN (152, 167, 658, 900))
```

How do I add this specific condition?

Comment: Its vague but maybe `WHERE (q.CUM_Rate <> 0 OR q.ReservationStayId IN (152, 167, 658, 900))`

Comment: `CUM_Rate` sounds dirty.

Comment: @FelixPamittan lol, it means Cummulative Rate!!

Comment: @Mihai Exactly what I needed! Currently my output gives 87,621 records, excluding all ReservationStayID with a CUM_Rate = 0. I wanted an exception for these specific ReservationStayID and as such, I should end up with 87,625 records. Your code did just that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons why `ReservationStayID`s `152`, `167`, `658`, `900`do not appear on your result:

1. No rows on `RESERVATIONLIST`, `WHERE STATUS <> 'CANCELED'`
2. No matching rows on `PKGREVENUE`

To solve your problem, you may want to turn the `INNER JOIN`s into a `LEFT JOIN`. Additionally, you may want to use a `CASE` expression in your `SUM() OVER` clause. And instead of using `AND` in your `WHERE` clause, you should use `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        --...,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN c.[Status] <> 'CANCELLED' THEN a.RateAmount
                ELSE 0
            END
            ) OVER(PARTITION BY a.ReservationStayID) AS 'CUM_Rate',
        --...
    FROM ReservationStayDate a
    LEFT  JOIN RESERVATIONLIST c    
        ON c.[ReservationStayID] = a.ReservationStayID 
        AND c.[MTH] = DATENAME(M, StayDate) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,StayDate) AS VARCHAR)
        AND c.[Status] <> 'CANCELED'
    LEFT JOIN PKGREVENUEd 
        ON d.[ReservationStayID] = a.ReservationStayID
        AND d.[StayDate] = a.StayDate   
) q
WHERE 
    q.CUM_Rate <> 0
    OR q.ReservationStayId IN (152, 167, 658, 900)
ORDER BY q.ReservationStayID, q.StayDate
```

*Note: I changed some of your `JOIN`s to directly use the table instead of using a subquery and `SELECT * FROM <table>`.*